# How to use my lumia 730 'share internet' feature with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, internet

With Windows, whenever I share internet from my phone, it was recognized in the wifi list. Ubuntu doesn't even realize that there is internet that is shared close to it. Do I have to change some settings or something?

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing obvious to do, if the wifi (driver etc) is working with other access points. I some rare cases it could happen that Ubuntu uses the wrong country code or the driver doesn't use all frequencies supported by the chip

Comment: The problem was this: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/827364)

Comment: That means you didn't find ANY network, not only the one of your phone. Then question and subject line are far far away from the problem...

Comment: Oh! I think the reason is that there was no other source of wifi in my up-country home. I could have asked it better. Am sorry.